# finding intervals for double integrals integration

Tags: integration

I have a joint pdf function

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} A, & \mbox{ } 0\le|x|+|y|<1\mbox{} \\ 0, & \mbox{otherwise } \mbox{ } \end{cases}
$$

I want to find value of A by using this formula: $$\int_{x}\int_{y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=1$$ which becomes after subsituting value: $$\int_{x}\int_{y}(A)dxdy=1$$ My question is how the values of 'x' and 'y' intervals are calculated from given information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $x$ must have $|x|\le 1$, i.e. must be in $[-1,1]$ in order that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ne 0$, so assume $x$ goes from $-1$ to $1$, *then* choose the right interval for $y$ (depending on $x$).

Comment: Thank you... so can we also do other way round, i mean pick y from -1 to 1 and choose interval for x?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: We get $|y|\le 1-|x|$, i.e. $y$ going from $|x|-1$ to $1-|x|$.

Answer (score 4):

$0\le|x|+|y|<1$ is area (without border) of square made by points $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. With area $2$.

If I understand correctly, it means that $A=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank You... sorry this may be very simple question.. but can you please explain, how we get 1/2 from 2, i mean why 2 is divided by 4?

Comment: Interpret the integral as volume - http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Volume_under_surface.png/220px-Volume_under_surface.png (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral) In your case it's cuboid with base area 2 (the square) and height A (we can ignore places where value of the function (or height) is $0$). And volume of this cuboid must be 1. It means $2A=1$. Or $A=1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

### Hint

First, plot your domain

[image: domain]

Since your PDF is constant, you integral is simply area of that square. But if you want to truly work it out and find the limits of integration, then split your integral into four and find limits for each of them, which shouldn't be a problem since all lines then will have a form $y = kx+b$

Comment: A picture is worth 1,000 words.

Comment: I share your opinion :)

Comment: It is enough to split it into two: e.g. $x=-1..0$ and $x=0..1$ and use $y=x-1\,..\,1-x$ and $y=1-x\,..\,x-1$ respectively.

Comment: @Berci it is, I agree.